# Customizing the Banno WebView?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We are currently building a chat plugin in the Banno mobile app, that opens a webview when clicking on a specific button.

Our goal is to offer Garden users the ability to minimize their webview (where the chat is presented) so that they can view their account data in the Garden, and then reopen the chat.

Opening our plugin in a new browser such as Chrome with the Banno bridge is not ideal, as it requires the user to switch apps, and then reenter their pin to access their account data. Is there a workaround to offer a minimize option or hide/show functionality to the webview?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to modify the frame of the plugin card at runtime.

If the plugin card is displayed on the dashboard, then the entire card is displayed to the user.

- https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/
- https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/restrictions/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will let our team know that we will need to use the done button after redirecting from the Banno Card to a full screen web view.